# restrict permissions on external drive

Tags: mac, permissions, external-hard-drive

- I'd like to set permissions on an external drive to 0750.
- I type: `chmod -R 0750 "/Volumes/My Book/"`
- `ls -l "/Volumes/My Book"` shows `drwxrwxrwx` for all of the sub-folders.
- I also tried `sudo chmod -R 0750 "/Volumes/My Book/"`  (This didn't even prompt me for a password.)
- The result is the same.  All permissions are `drwxrwxrwx`

Is there a way to do this?  OS Catalina, if that's relevant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your external drive is probably formatted as FAT32 or exFAT or another filesystem type that doesn't support Unix file permissions. You can check this by looking at the "type" column of `diskutil list`.

If that's the problem, back up any data you care about to another drive, *test your backup*, and then reformat the problem drive to use a GUID Partition Table (GPT) and APFS if you're only using this on Macs.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and then mark this as correct.